# designing database schema

Tags: database-design, orm

I am trying to develop some database schema.Now i have one Article A and then i have a set of articles related to it.

Which of the approaches should i use?

ArticleID, ArticleName,RelatedArticles 
(Related article is comma seperated values of articleid_

OR
I can have 2 tables as follows:
Article

```
ArticleID, ArticleName

RelatedArticle
ArticleId,RelatedArticleID
```

and i can query easily as
`select * from  article a,RelatedArticle a where a.ArticleID = b.ArticleID`.

How can i may it to a class structure of bibernate;

Answer (score 3):

Storing multiple values in a single field goes against the atomicity required by the first normal form. This is almost always a bad idea.

Use a separate table for matching related articles instead. Hibernate should be able to deal with this, by having the article class contain a list of related articles.

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship between an article and its related articles is exclusive parent-child, i.e. for a given article there may be many related sub-articles, but these sub-articles cannot be related to any other article, then you can have a simpler 1-table design with columns as articleId, ArticleName, and parentArticleId (nullable).